# Conditional probit to unconditional model?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, probit

I have a study in R in which I use public disclosures from companies and stock market data to estimate the probability that a new public disclosure (dividend announcement, etc...) will be published:

\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
    Pr(D_{i, t}=1|X) = \Phi(X^T\beta),
\end{equation}

where $D_{i,t}$ has a value of 1 if there is a new disclosure by firm $i$ in day $t$, otherwise 0. Parameter $X^T$ is a vector of regressors, containing the return and volatility of firm $i$ in day $t$.

The content of my study is not that important. The question is about my model which is a very simple probit model. But showing it to my teacher he said that my model is a "conditional test on the probability of publishing a public disclosure" (Ok, this I understand). And then he asks me "how I would specify an unconditional version of the test".

So I have two questions:

1 - Is there anything wrong with my Probit or is every Probit a conditional test (or at least in the way I wrote the equation)?

2 - How should I answer his question? Is he talking about a simple change in the formula/notation or there is a way to transform a probit model into an unconditional version of it?

I think he wants me to use the conditional probability formula to transform the equation into something else. But I don't know if I'm being dumb and/or missing something.

Comment: The condition in your conditional probability are the predictor values. An unconditional probability would thus be the "a priori" probability without knowing the predictors. This can be useful, e.g., as a abseline aginst which to compare the prediction accuracy of your model.

Comment: @cdalitz hmmmmm, I don't know if I understood. So to answer his question should I use a different model, for example, a Linear Discriminant Analysis? Since the LDA models the distribution of predictors X?

Comment: The unconditional probabilities (aka "a priori" probabilities) do not require to fit a model: simply compute the overall proportions of the outcomes irrespective of the feature/predictor values. OTOH there seems ot be something fundamentally wrong with your student-teacher relationship, if you do not dare to ask your teacher for things you do not understand. Your teacher most ceratinly will welcome it, if you ask.

Comment: @cdalitz thank you, I asked him last night but thanks to the holidays I'll have to wait a little for the answer ahahaha